# Passing arrays in to the function in bash script

Tags: arrays, bash, syntax

I am new to bash script and writing the bash script. I have declared an array and i have given the values.
But When i pass the array in the loop values are not getting inside the loop.
Below is my code

```
 declare -a files=( "A1S0" "D1S0" "D2S0" "D3S0" "D4S0" "D5S0" "D6S0" )   

     command_to_get_filesizes() {


        for i in ${#files[@]}; do
         echo test
        echo "${files[@]}"
        echo files[$i]

        echo  $(date +%m)
        aws s3api list-objects --bucket ui-dl-weather-ecmwf-ltf --prefix daily/ --query "Contents[?contains(Key, 'files[$i]$(date +%m%d)')]" --output text | awk '{print $2, $4}' >> "$FILESIZE"
        }
  command_to_get_filesizes()
```

Can u pls help me on this.. `'files[$i]$(date +%m%d)'` array values should come in this place

```
eg: 'A1S0[$i]$(date +%m%d)'
```

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 1):

Wrong syntax. What is the `#` doing there? Correct would be

```
 for i in "${files[@]}"; do

    echo Processing file $i
    .... 
    aws s3api list-objects --bucket ui-dl-weather-ecmwf-ltf --prefix daily/ --query "Contents[?contains(Key, '$i$(date +%m%d)')]" --output text | awk '{print $2, $4}' >> "$FILESIZE"

 done
```

Comment: As suggested above, i tried, but $i is not printing anything...
Can u pls help me on this

Comment: `$i` is printing the values as 1,2,3,4 instaed of values in the array

Comment: It does not, as you can easily see by trying out this code in a bash command line: `declare -a files=( "A1S0" "D1S0" "D2S0"); for i in "${files[@]}"; do echo $i; done`. Make sure to really copy and paste what I wrote.